# Suppress console output for production build

Tags: typescript, tsc

I need to keep console output clean in production mode, but i need logs for development.
What compiler options or tsc's cli options can help me with that?

P.S. I'm using just `tsc --build` for build in production mode

Comment: UPDATE: I ended up using babel with plugin https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-remove-console. I just apply it to compiled files.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not possible to do with the TypeScript compiler. According to Ryan Cavanaugh (the development lead of the TypeScript team):

> Lots of tools available that don't need a type system or complex downleveling to accomplish this; we're not trying to be a Swiss Army Knife

[Source](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18785#issuecomment-332549669)

Your best option is to use some other tool to accomplish this task.

Comment: Do you know some small tools to accomplish that? I can do this with webpack but i think this is overhead :-)

Comment: @ user13475226 - you add it to the build step that before your run your code through typescript you would look through files for matching strings and remove them. If there's a `package.json` file in the project then you can provide an npm script to run **anything**, consider a typescript file that does the aforementioned? or any other language, or use GulpJs.